# What is the first 21 digit prime in consecutive digits of $e$?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, education

This is a challenge question from a bitcoin giveaway on an image I recently saw

In order to find the 10th digit of $e$ I saw a few individuals write a line of code for it, I wanted to replicate it for the 21st but I know nothing of code. [This is the link to the giveaway itself.](http://twitter.com/Phemex_official/status/1217808220703473664)

Edit (NOT OP) :

1.Where can one get as many digits of $e$ as needed from? so that keep checking every 21 blocks for being prime

2.What is a quick way to check 21 digit odd numbers quickly for primality?

Comment: Do you mean 21 consecutive digits, each of which is prime?

Comment: Can you define what a "21-prime digit" is please?

Comment: Yes, the first 21 consecutive digits, each of which is a prime.

Comment: A bitcoin giveaway on an image I recently saw.

Comment: Can you describe the problem with some useful information? What is a bitcoin giveaway ? what image? why does it matter that you tell us that you dont know programming or math ? how does that gives any information about this problem? Try to include useful information, this is really low quality as it is.

Comment: In order to find the 10th digit of E I saw a few individuals write a line of code for it, I wanted to replicate it for the 21st but I know nothing of code. This is the link to the giveaway itself. https://twitter.com/Phemex_official/status/1217808220703473664

Comment: The image in fact asks for the first $21$-digit prime, not the first "$21$-prime digit". That's the first string of $21$ consecutive digits that form a (single) prime in decimal notation. They don't specify any rules for the challenge. It's very easy to find that prime, since each of the $21$-digit substrings has probability about $\frac1{\log10^{21}}\approx2\%$ to be prime and you can easily test them with an almost-certain probabilistic prime test. So probably they'll want a proof that this is in fact a prime.

Comment: Just test every block of $21$ digits whether the resulting number is a prime number. Also note that we cannot start with digit $0$ since this would not give a $21$-digit number. So small numbers can efficiently be proven to be prime. Even proving $100$ digit-numbers to be prime is absolutely routine.

Comment: My favourite for such tasks if pari/gp , but there are tons of other software-tools that can solve this "problem" almost immediately once the routine has been programmed. pari/gp is extremely easy to handle. Everyone can write programs with it after a few hours of studying how it works.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I think this is basically numerology.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : I have edited the question from OP's comments and can see what they are trying to ask and what the motivation is for. before this question getting closed I'll try to improve it's quality and help OP to express what they are trying to say.

Comment: @Peter : You should post your comment as an answer.

Comment: @Arjang Although I tend to agree Jyrki, I post an answer giving at least the necessary steps. Maybe, I can motivate the OP to learn how to program with PARI/GP.

Comment: @Peter : forget the OP! I want to know :)

Comment: @Arjang Then, I hope my answer is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

To solve this problem :

$1)$ Download PARI/GP

$2)$ Calculate e as accurate as you want, even 1 million digits do not take very long. You just have to establish enough memory with allocatemem()

$3)$ Convert each block of length $21$ that does not begin with a $0$ with the command isprime(,2) which is a rigorous primality test. The best way is probably to create an array with the digits-command.

$4)$ The first such block is the answer.

I did not post the full code, but I mentioned the necessary commands. I want to leave a little work to the OP.